# How to copy code from github without line number?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

When copying code from Github repos and then pasting to VS Code, code comes with the line numbers. Only way to get rid of the numbers on copying is viewing the file in the raw format.

But the problems is I am trying upgrade react-native by looking at the diffs between commits and copy the code from that screen which is not a raw view.

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.5&to=0.63.2

I search the web for an answer but couldn't find a way.

Does anybody know a workaround for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no way to do this, so for now I am using select columns by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, then click and drag with the mouse to select all the line numbers in one go in VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

Install git on your machine. Do a bit clone. You can then stage and commit to your local git. Finally, you can push the change to GitHub via the command line.

Comment: Thanks @Tarik, That is the way to go when you are dealing with many changes but my problem is I only need to get 20-30 line from that repo and every time I copy and paste from the github line numbers just gets into clipboard. I am curious if there is a way to copy code with the line numbers

Comment: Why not pulling everything, copying the changed files locally then pushing should do the job. Not sure what you are trying to do, but since you are in to do it manually, it's just an extra click away to get the raw source code.